# Firebase Remote Config only shows correct value on second App launch

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, capacitor, firebase-remote-config

I am using Firebase Remote config in a capacitor.js App using `@capacitor-firebase/remote-config` firebase plugin. I have the parameter set for `first_open` and the conditions are true if the `first_open` is after a set date and false if before the date. Default is set to false.

important part to the code is:

```
async function initializeSubscribe() {
  try {
     await Capacitor.Plugins.FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchConfig({
       minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds: 0,
     });

    Capacitor.Plugins.FirebaseRemoteConfig.activate()
 .then(async () => {                     
    const data = await Capacitor.Plugins.FirebaseRemoteConfig.getBoolean({
            key: "first_user",
          });

          const user = data.value;
          console.log("first_user:", user);
          handleRemoteConfig(user, isDateValid);
      
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

I've tried adding `settimeout` as a possible solution but I can't get it to retrieve the value the first time.

This happens only in iOS, Android has no issue with it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/issues/364) was recently resolved and will be published with the next release.
You can install the dev version:

npm i @capacitor-firebase/remote-config@1.4.0-dev.5d562ff.1681878046

Comment: I saw that on Github just after I posted this and installing the dev version worked.